# Asp.Net web application database autoUpdate functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a functionality to update my web application database using data from an xml file. I want this database to be updated after ever 24hrs. My problem is I do not know where and how in the code should I call this method such that it does not have to be triggered by a button click and its executes after every 24hrs.
Please Help.

Comment: One approach would be to put the code which updates your database into its own application, and create a windows scheduled task which runs at a certain time of day. Have a look here - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Thanks Alex..... but is there another option where I can I have it in the same application.

Comment: It is possible, but will require some more work. I will answer in a moment as the explanation is getting too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem with background tasks in ASP.NET is that you don't have a standard application running to kick off your threads.

If you start firing off background tasks in the webapp, you can end up with inconsistent behaviour if something causes your appdomain to fail, your task can be stopped part-way, which if you're updating a DB could be a serious issue.

The most flexible way to implement this is using a seperate application running on a windows scheduled task which updates the DB for you. This separates the task from the webapp completely, but can be awkward to maintain.
It does however mean that even if your webapp is offline for whatever reason, the DB is still updated so long as the server running the task is working at the time.

If you do wish to embed the task in the webapp, something akin to cron would be preferable, as it will allow you to fire the task according to a set of rules, and leave it to its own devices.

Quartz Scheduler can achieve this, but can be fiddly to get working, and is sometimes overkill for simple tasks. It is worth learning for more involved systems which require a lot of tasks running in complex schedules, and allows the use of cron expressions.

HangFire is a different solution to the same problem, and is somewhat more simple than Quartz Scheduler, while still allowing cron configuration for tasks.

Using HangFire, the following will trigger the task at midnight every day (where `UpdateDB` is the method which runs the update).

`RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => UpdateDB(), "0 0 0 * * ?");`

For your needs, HangFire is probably the quickest way to get this working.

The following will give you an overview of HangFire : http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/quick-start.html

HangFire is available in the NuGet archive so you can add it very quickly using the NuGet packages context menu, and documentation for timed tasks is here : http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html

Hopefully this is enough to get you started.